# String types not allowed at a textStyle

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

Why i can't use this textStyle!

**Error**: Error:(20, 36) String types not allowed (at 'textStyle' with value 'font_family_light').

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView2"
  android:padding="20dp"
  android:textStyle="normal|font_family_light"
  android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
  android:background="@drawable/text_background"
  android:layout_margin="18dp"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="left"
  android:text="text..."
  android:textSize="17sp"/>
```

Comment: you can use font programmatically in java code

Comment: I prefer to use it in XML im new in Android development and im using fragments and activites so for is better  to use text styles in XML thanks

Comment: Refer this link--> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html

Answer (score 0):

TextStyle can have value - normal, bold and italic.
Please refer:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textStyle